# Chat implemenatation leads to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for <PACKAGE>.databinding.ActivityChatBindingImpl

Tags: android, getstream-io

Trying to implement the chat from [this example](https://getstream.io/tutorials/android-chat/#java) but I keep getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for PACKAGE.databinding.ActivityChatBindingImpl

(not mentioning the package name, not necessary I believe)

Activity is called ChatActivity and XML (layout) file is "activity_chat.xml", exactly the same as from example so I don't need to post code here. I enabled databinding inside gradle file and tried putting the

> android.databinding.enableV2=false

but this doesn't resolve the issue. What can be the issue here?

Also, looking at the DataBindingUtil.java class, I see that "DataBinderMapperImpl" is not generated for some reason.

Comment: please share your gradle file here; do you use proguard?

Comment: Please make sure you built the project once you added <layout> tag in xml for databinding.  Build will generate BidningImpl.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. However, I managed to run the app when I changed package name from (example) "com.test.Test" to "com.test.test" however, I would like to keep the previous package name and not need to upload a new app to the store. What should I do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there having this issue, the only thing that helped is I had to change the package name, since mine was for example: "com.example.Example" and I changed it to all lowercase and that fixed the issue. However I did not change the "applicationId" (only folder names) therefore app does not need to be uploaded under the different package name again.